# Can't get Glossaries to work (Beginner)

Tags: errors, glossaries

I'm honestly sorry for my stupid question but i just cannot get [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to function. I'm constantly reading that I should execute some sort of pearl script where i need a pearl processor or something.

I'm currently on a Windows 7 Computer with a pretty new and intact MikTeX installation using TeXmaker as Client.

I tried multiple times creating new .tex files and copy & pasting minimal examples but I just cant get it to work

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
 fontsize=11pt,
 a4paper,
 pdflatex
 ]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{Blindtext}              

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries         

\begin{document}

\section{Story of an Apple}
\Blindtext

\section{Story of a Pear}
\Blindtext


\newglossaryentry{apple}{ name=apple, description={it's used as an example fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{ name=pear, description={it's used as an example fruit}}
\glsaddall


\end{document}
```

It's sadly not working. Would be really cool if you guys could help me

Also the compiler tells me this:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tracklang.sty' not found.
```

[(click here for full log)](http://pastebin.com/QWJtNpQy)

I already doublechecked. The File is installed. Also my MikTeX installation isn't older than a month.

Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know the term `MWE`? It's a pretty nice feature ;-)

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for uploading the `MWE`. I just copied and compiled it: It runs out of the box on TeXLive 2014 (freeze state april 2015) and Linux

Comment: Welp. Now I know that I did understand it correctly. Maybe I need to redownload tracklang.sty

Comment: Yes, that's the best thing you can do

Comment: Make sure that your package database is up-to-date by using in the package manager (user and admin version) repositories->synchronize.

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what i did (didnt even know that this thing extsits). Now it compiles and everything is fine. I'll answer the question asn soon as I get this fully working. I currently dont know how to display the glossar. The MWE from above prints both blindtexts but no glossary

Comment: @JonasDralle: `\printglossaries` ;-)

Comment: It's still not working. [Heres a MWE](http://pastebin.com/dYxB0uTB). Do I need to compile with some specific setting? It outputs no errors and perfectly created a hyperlink at "computer" and "cd" but prints no glossary. [Here are my "quick translate" settings](https://i.imgur.com/SqKhLK1.png "I set it to the one with a blue circle. You know.").

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251571) help?

Comment: It's already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ran your MWE (well done, by the way), and you're just missing one line:  put it before `\end{document}`.

```
\printglossaries
```

Make sure you're compiling your `.tex` file; then compiling your glossary with `makeglossaries` on your .glo file; then compiling our `.tex` file again.  With this process, adding the above line to your MWE printed the glossary just fine.  (I also replaced `Blindtext` with `lipsum`, because I have the latter and the not the former.)

```
\documentclass[
 fontsize=11pt,
 a4paper,
 pdflatex
 ]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}              
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries         
\begin{document}
\section{Story of an Apple}
\lipsum
\section{Story of a Pear}
\lipsum
\newglossaryentry{apple}{ name=apple, description={it's used as an example fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{pear}{ name=pear, description={it's used as an example fruit}}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```