# Glossary remains empty

Tags: glossaries

I want to add a glossary to my document. On this website: [Glossaries](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) I found an example and tried it on my machine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

As a result I got 2 pages, with the second page, where the actual glossary should appear, being empty.
However, these 2 files have been created:

- myDoc.glsdefs
- myDoc.glo

I also compiled my document several times.

When compiling the very same example on Sharelatex.com (an online Latex compiler), everything worked as intended (the second page wasn't empty).

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` or directly the indexing program (`xindy`/`makeindex`)?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I executed `\makeglossaries` at the beginning of my document (as can be seen in this example). In Texmaker I also have `makeindex %.idx` as Makeindex command, but I'm not sure, whether it's being executed.

Comment: There is a bit more behind it, that would call makeindex to generate an index, not a glossary (or related). Please have a look at [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms ](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms). There is a section describing the use of `makeindex`. Alternatively, look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767), the procedure is the same with `makeglossaries`.

Comment: @user1170330: No, you normally need to run the program `makeglossaries` as well

Answer (score 8):

(As an aside, I don't understand why the file `myDoc.glsdefs` was created from the document you provided as this file is only created if `\newglossaryentry` is used inside the `document` environment. This file is certainly not created when I tried the example. Make sure that you keep all `\newglossaryentry` commands in the preamble or you can have them in a separate file and load it using `\loadglsentries`.)

However, as others have mentioned in the comments, it's necessary to run another application after LaTeX has created your PDF file. This step is required to create the glossary file which is then input the next time you LaTeX (build/compile/typeset) your document. So the steps are:

1. Run (pdf)LaTeX to create `myDoc.pdf`
2. Run the indexing application to create `myDoc.gls`
3. Run (pdf)LaTeX to create `myDoc.pdf` which should now include the glossary.

Step 2 is the place where many people get stuck. There are two indexing applications: `makeindex` and `xindy`. All TeX distributions should have `makeindex` installed. This is a pre-compiled application so it doesn't need anything extra to run it, but it's hard-coded for the English alphabet and doesn't support UTF-8. The other indexing application, `xindy`, is much more flexible and has rules for different languages, but it's a Perl script, which means that you need to have Perl installed to run it.

In your document you just have

```
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
```

This means that the default `makeindex` application is assumed, and the `glossaries` package will create the files `myDoc.glo` and `myDoc.ist`, which can be read by the `makeindex` application.

If instead you have

```
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
```

then `glossaries` will create the files `myDoc.glo` and `myDoc.xdy`, which can be read by `xindy`.

It can be a bit of a nuisance trying to remember whether to use `makeindex` or `xindy` and what options to pass to the appropriate application, so `glossaries` comes with a Perl script called `makeglossaries` which will read the `myDoc.aux` file and will run `makeindex` or `xindy` for you. (Don't confuse the external `makeglossaries` script with the `\makeglossaries` command in your document.) If you use a [command prompt](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/terminal.html) then you can build your document using the following application calls:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The reason your example worked fine when you used ShareLaTeX was because ShareLaTeX detected that you needed to run `makeglossaries` and did that for you behind the scenes.

If you don't have Perl installed then you can't use the `makeglossaries` script, but you can use a simplified Lua script that's now also provided with the `glossaries` package. This script is bundled with the file name `makeglossaries-lite.lua` but you may find that your TeX distribution provides it with a different name. For example, TeX Live on Unix-like systems create a symbolic link `makeglossaries-lite` which omits the `.lua` extension. In this case the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries-lite myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Alternatively you can run `makeindex` directly:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeindex -s myDoc.ist -t myDoc.glg -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you don't use a terminal or command prompt, that is, you just click on a button or menu item to build your PDF, then how you run the indexing application depends on the text editor that you are using (for example, TeXWorks, TeXnicCenter, WinEdt). Each editor has a different way of adding a new tool, so the instructions will be different, but most will have an example in the manual that you might be able to modify. I have an example of how to add `makeglossaries` to TeXWorks in [Building Your Document](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/build.html) . On this site there's:

- [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)
- [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099)

If all else fails, there are two fallback methods. If you have at least version 4.08 of the `glossaries` package you can add the `automake` package option:

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```

This requires the `\write18` mode to be enabled, but now you just need to run (pdf)LaTeX twice:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

This will run `makeindex` for you. Since the shell escape is a security risk, the default mode is usually restricted to only allowing trusted applications to run. The trusted list usually includes `makeindex` but doesn't include `xindy`. Some systems may completely disable the shell escape, in which case the `automake` option won't work for either `makeindex` or `xindy`. Search the `.log` file for instances of `runsystem` to find out if the application was allowed to run.

The other fallback method will [slow the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml) as it will use TeX to sort and collate the glossary entries instead of using the more efficient `makeindex` or `xindy` applications. In this case you need to replace

```
\makeglossaries
```

with

```
\makenoidxglossaries
```

and replace

```
\printglossaries
```

with

```
\printnoidxglossaries
```

(Or replace `\printglossary` with `\printnoidxglossary`.) For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package provides another method that doesn't require an external application, but with this method the glossary lists *all* defined entries in the order of definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

The build method is now simply:

```
pdflatex myDoc
```

A comparison of all the different methods is given in section [1.1 Indexing Options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:indexingoptions) in the `glossaries` user manual.

Finally, if you need to call external applications, such as `makeglossaries`, `makeindex` or `bibtex`, you might want to look at one of the [automation tools](http://ctan.org/topic/compilation), such as [arara](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara), which will run all the required applications for you.